Solana Arbitrage Program
Is there any literature on Solana Arbitrage?  Point me in the right direction.
Can someone explain to me how to build this type of Program.

If you are completely new, you might want to check the previous iteration of the Solana BootCamp where Joe builds an arbitrage program. It's a bit dated but with some elbow grease you can run the programs. Prior completion of the last quest is required for this.
GitHub -> https://github.com/solana-developers/pirate-bootcamp/tree/main/quest-5
YouTube -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiA_pBftFt4&list=PLilwLeBwGuK6NsYMPP_BlVkeQgff0NwvU&index=5
You can also check out articles of MEV on Solana with articles such as

https://www.umbraresearch.xyz/writings/mev-on-solana
https://www.helius.dev/blog/solana-mev-an-introduction

